# AWS AppFlow | Incremental pull from Salesforce

Tags: amazon-web-services, salesforce

Does AWS AppFlow provides the support for incremental data pull? I don't find any support on that.

Comment: What do you mean, incremental. Please explain your use case

Comment: Incremental mean delta data. Assume you did first time pull yesterday and if you do the pull today it should give me 1 day data (i.e. delta only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

On the `Configure flow` page there is an option for `Transfer new data only. After the flow is activated, transfer new data only`.

This is the default setting